# strip multiple trailing dashes and numbers from string

Tags: php

I want to strip all trailing dashes and numbers from a file name.

```
Filename:
Filename-01-1 and sometimes Filename-01
```

My code only works fine when the file name is in the second format.

```
rtrim(preg_replace("/\d+$/","",$Filename),'-')
```

also tried

```
rtrim(preg_replace('/[0-9]+/',"",$Filename),'-')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/(-|\d+)*$/",'', $filename);
```

Explaination

```
(-|\d+) # match "-" literally OR any digit
*       # match the previous group zero or more times 
$       # end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your regex to also include the dash character:

```
preg_replace("/[\d\-]+$/","",$Filename)
```

The problem with your attempts was that you were first replacing trailing numbers, then removing trailing dashes. But if the filename was in the format `Filename-1-1`, then only the final number was being matched.